# Attempting to write readonly database Django + Gunicorn + nginx + sqlite3

Tags: python, django, nginx, sqlite, gunicorn

The problem may sound trivial at first.

My server runs on nginx and gunicorn. Django 1.11.4, db: sqlite3.

The problem is raised when I try to enter as an admin to my fresh new project with almost no data. Right after I log in the OperationalError is raised and says 'attempt to write a readonly database". I have surfed the internet and the solutions below don't work in my case:

- chmod to 777 the DB (raises "can't open file" issue. FullPath doesn't work as well)
- chown to a+w

The whole project runs on "supervisor"  and, unfortunately, I coulnd't find the solution to this problem

My supervisor file

```
[program:majorpack]
command=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn project.wsgi:application -c 
/var/www/django/project/project/project/gunicorn.conf.py
directory=/var/www/django/project/project
user=nobody
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```

Gunicorn.conf.py

```
bind = '127.0.0.1:8000'
workers = 3
user = "nobody"
```

nginx default file

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 111.222.333.44; #либо ip, либо доменное имя
access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;

location /static/ {
    root /opt/myenv/myproject/;
    expires 30d;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; 
    proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
```

And the ls -lp log (Editted)

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 django   django    4096 Aug 23 00:17 ../
drwxrwxrwx 5 www-data www-data  4096 Aug 23 09:35 client/
-rw-r-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 57344 Aug 23 09:49 db.sqlite3
drwxrwxrwx 6 www-data www-data  4096 Aug 23 09:35 home/
drwxrwxrwx 3 www-data www-data  4096 Aug 23 09:08 project/
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data   807 Aug 23 00:17 manage.py
drwxrwxrwx 6 www-data www-data  4096 Aug 23 09:35 personnel/
drwxrwxrwx 5 www-data www-data  4096 Aug 23 09:50 static/
```

Any help is appreciated.

PS: no, I dont have the etc/init/gunicorn.conf the gunicorn.conf.py is for that.

Comment: wel, it looks like you're running gunicorn as user `nobody` whereas your db is set to write only for `www-data`. Have you tried running gunicorn as `www-data`? (pls edit your question with the new `ls -lp` log if your db.sqlite3 permissions are set differently, which you seem to indicate at the top of your question).

Comment: @dirkgroten I have changed both supervisor and gunicorn file for www-data, now it raises "unable to open database file".

Comment: Show the error stack trace

Comment: Thank you for your help. But i have changed my db to pg. Fortunately there's much more feedback on the internet.